# How to update fragments under navigation tabs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, navigationbar

I have four tabs in navigation tab, and each tab has a fragment:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new PostJob();
                case 1:{
                    return new PostedJobHistory();
                }
                case 2:{
                    return new SearchCandidates();
                }
                case 3:{
                    return new EmployerSettings();
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
```

I enter job details in first tab - PostJob fragment. and want to get it updated in the second tab when I go to Posted Job history fragment.

How can I achieve this. 
In tab 1 I enter details in database
and in tab 2 i read database to show posted job history, but posted job history is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
List<Fragment> fragmentsList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragmentsList == null || fragmentsList.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (Fragment fragment : fragmentsList) {
        if (fragment instanceof PostedJobHistory) {
            ((PostedJobHistory) fragment).yourUpdateMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this has to called from activity/fragment that contains your navigation tabs so you can either use listenter or call ((YourActivityName)getActivity()).updatingMethod() this method should contain above code if navigation tab is in a fragment then use ((YourActivityName)getParentFragment()).updatingMethod() 

call it whenever you need to update the data

Comment: did it work? update status and i will check for some other solution

Comment: I need to write the updatingMethod(); all over again, it involves database access and many things. Isn't there a way to call onCreateView explicitly.